# How to use "Considering" preposition in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

According to  the Longman Dictionary, *considering* is "used to say that you are thinking about a particular fact when you are giving your opinion."

The Cambridge Dictionary says that is "used to mention a particular condition or fact about something, usually a **disadvantage**."

Can I use *considering* in a positive way, to express my opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

> They're very similar; but considering that it comes with twice the storage and costs $100 less, I'd buy the HP rather than the Dell.

It is true that *considering* is often used to mention a disadvantage which must be taken into account in an evaluation; but as often as not it points to this disadvantage in order to support a positive opinion.

> This is a very well-written essay, especially considering that the author has only been studying English for a year.

But that is not obligatory; the consideration may support a negative opinion.

> Considering his vile temper, his lackluster quality of work and his complete lack of elementary tact, I think we would be ill advised to offer Bob a permanent position.

All *considering* means is that your opinion includes consideration of the object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; do you agree that "Longman Dictionary" offers better explanation than "Cambridge Dictionary"?

Comment: @Abbas Amiri: It's just that the Cambridge definition happens to mention the context in which "considering" is often used. Which arguably makes it a *worse* definition, if it's left you with the impression that somehow the word itself carries "negative" connotations. As StoneyB says, it can be used in positive, neutral, and negative contexts - any "value judgement" comes from the *other* words in the statement, not from "considering".